# Pagination with Search form not working

Tags: yii, pagination

I am implementing pagination on my search result, on the very first page it is working fine, but the problem is when i click on 2 for second page results, it displays empty page.

In view i have:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                                             'itemView'=>'_listing'));
```

while in my controller i have:

```
if (isset($_POST)
{    
    (......)
    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($results,array(
                                                      'keyField' => 'brand_id',
                                                      'pagination'=>array(
                                                      'pageSize'=>5,
                                                  )));

    //echo "<pre>";  print_r($dataProvider);exit;

    $this->render('listing',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 'post' => $_POST));
}
```

The `$results` contains my search results, controller has a check if post is set or not, so when request for load of second page is sent to listing action, the post data is not set, so it does not enters the code and displays nothing.

How to make post data available to action when call for second page is done?

Comment: Why do you use CArrayDataProvider? Can you show the search implementation, I bet there is better way to do it. Also searches are used to DISPLAY, not change data in the database, so use GET instead of POST - its the proper and more user friendly way to do it - the user can send the search url to someone else to show the same results he has found.

Comment: I have used CArrayDataProvider because i have already fetched search data in my controller in array variable $results, i just need $results to be displayed via pagination, and did i said i am changing data in database??
what if i have several variables say 10 or say 11, you stil suggest to use GET?? yeah its a user friendly way but thats not the thing i am concerned of..

problem is how to make data available on second call by pagination??

Comment: I never said you are changing data - this is exactly why you SHOULD use GET. Even if you have 30 variables, I'd suggest GET for seaches. Regardless of that, why don't you use CActiveDataProvider no matter if you use POST or GET? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider "Already have" - you have obtained it somehow, if you use CActiveDataProvider you can get the data with the `->getData()` method if you need it for something beside the pagination. CArrayDataProvider is an utility just for cases like external APIs data.

Comment: Ok fine, suppose i am using CActiveDataprovider, now when it paginates data, it sets ajax links on linker below, suppose i have to see page 2 results so when i click on it, obviously it will call my action again to have further data, i have already set check condition if data is set or not, so you mean to say CActiveDataProvider will skip the check?? and CArrayDataProvider is unable to do that?? This is what you saying??
MY main problem is simple: How to skip that check while calling second page to load..as simple as that..Thank you..:)

Comment: CActiveDataProvider will automatically set the LIMIT and OFFSET in the query, based on the default page GET param. When you obtain your results and put them in CArrayDataDataProvider, you obviously don't slice them properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
      'itemView'=>'_listing',
      'ajaxUpdate'=>'#divViewPanel',
      'enablePagination'=>true
));
```